# Nuxt.js refresh url get 404 not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have one problem on my nuxt.js project.

I create dynamic page like `https://samplesite.com/place/{place_id}` which place_id dynamic value. (I have around 4,000+ places in my database)

after I run `npm run generate` and get /dist folder, then I push this folder to amazon EC2.

Everything work well, when I click a like on index page to /place/{place_id} page, website show place information.

But when I push refresh button on web browser, the page /place/{place_id} show 404 not found.

Do you have any solution to fix this problem?

I read on nuxt.js website, they said I need to generate dynamic page but my place is about 4,000 places, I think it's impossible to generate all of place page.

Please tell me what should I do.

Comment: You need to  supply that data from server side

Comment: Can you screenshot the error when you reload 404

Comment: Sorry for reopening it, i'm just having the same problem but i'm compiling with command `npm run build` of Vue CLI. Also, it happens with dinamyc and statics routes, the only one route that i can reload is the index. I uploaded it on an Apache server in Azure. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 6):

create a .htaccess file and put the below code into it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where to put this file?

Comment: @RustamRavshanovich in the root where you have the index.html file

Answer (score 5):

## Do you have a fix set of dynamic routes?

If you do, you can use function to [generate the static site](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#routes)

```
In 2.13.0, `nust` introduced a `target: static` feature, make sure to 
check [it](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static) out.
```

## Do you care about the SEO?

If you do care the SEO, you can use SSR in Nuxt, which is the `universal` mode. The other choice is the above static site genration

## Do you have a SPA site?

If you do, you can use `spa` mode and refer to the nginx setting showed [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

## If you don't know the exact dynamic routes, don't care about SEO for dynamic routes, you can combine the static site generation with dynamic routes.

In `universal` mode, use `nuxt generate` to generate a static site.

In the [generate config](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/), define a custom page for SPA fallback:

```
export default {
  generate: {
    fallback: "custom_sap_fallbackpage.html"
  }
}
```

Then in Nginx, define the same fallback page for unknown route, like:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /custom_sap_fallbackpage.html;
}
```

If you set `fallback: true`, Nuxt will use 404.html as the default fallback page, unless you configure nginx to ignore its own default 404 page, nginx will still show you the default nginx 404 page. I think a custom fallback page is the easiest way to do the static site generation and SPA mixing.

In this approach, static page will be pre-rendered, dynamic routes is treated as unknown route for nginx, which use the fallback SPA page to render.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run generate` does not support dynamic routes. Because it doesn't know how to build the `{{pageid}}.html`.

From nuxt docs:

> Dynamic routes are ignored by the generate command.

see: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes